# Bitmap gravity set to center not filling the screen even though the image is big enough

Tags: android, image, android-layout, bitmap, android-drawable

I have a RelativeLayout in my Android project. This has it's background set to a Bitmap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/splash2" />
```

`splash2` is a PNG image sized 2560x1440 pixels. I haven't set the background of the layout directly to the image, because the default scale mode (or gravity) is `fill` which stretches the image to fit the screen. With `center` it should take correct size image from the center and show it unscaled. In case of a vertical 1080x1920 screen, it should take that big piece and center it in the layout.

However, I have a problem. The image is bigger than any screen out in the market today. Still, with my Nexus 7, which has a 1920x1080 screen, it has borders around the image. The layout is set to full screen. The image is shrinked vertically.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: place splash2.png in res/drawable-nodpi

Comment: @pskink This didn't help. I had previously copied the same image in different folders. Thanks for pointing out `drawable-nodpi` though. This will save some space.

Comment: so now you. have it in one folder (nodpi) it has gravity=center (thus not scaled)  and still y9u say that png doest cover the whole screen?

Comment: @pskink The behavior is the same as pointed in the question.

Comment: its strange a bit, did you try a hierarchyviewer ?

Comment: This also happens on my Nexus 5.

Comment: and when you change gravity to "fill" your image covers all of your screen (but its stretched of course) ?

Comment: @pskink Yes, it stretches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageView's scale type `centerCrop` was what I wanted. Unfortunately I couldn't specify this property for bitmaps. I changed my splash screen layout to FrameLayout and added an ImageView and TextView overlapping each other. This way I was able to achieve what I wanted.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roadSignName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="My program"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `android:gravity="fill"` to cover  vertical & horizontal direction

Comment: `fill` causes image stretching

Answer (score 5):

For splash image try gravity="center|fill"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center|fill"
            android:src="@drawable/fondo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: wrong, `center|fill` has the same effect as standalone `fill` = image is stretched which is terrible

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to the bitmap:

```
android:gravity="fill_vertical"
```

This should fix it.

P.S. Sorry for the first answer, I edited it now.

Comment: Bitmaps don't have `scaleType` property.

Comment: You are correct, this fills the screen vertically, but this stretches the image. It doesn't crop a correct sized piece.

Comment: Why don't you use a classic ImageView then? I find it much easier to work with.